# PostgreSQL, pg_dump and pg_restore and object dependency order

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a question. 
Is there any way to force PostgreSQL 9.3 backup / restore schema in the correct sequence of dependent objects? (for example: 
I need to create a function that is used in the materialized views before creating the materialized views itself). I got an error in schema restoring, because the materialized view is created before creating function itself.

Thanks

Comment: Before the dumping pg_dump does a topological sort of the objects, based on their dependancies, and attempts to dump based on this order. This will cause a warning during the dump if any cyclic dependancies are detected . In your case you should probably apply the `create function` parts manually after the resore itself. (pg_dump --schema only will give only the ddl, can be used to extract the function definitions, and/or materialised view definitions)